# Hebrew translation for the Deuterocanonical books?

Tags: bible-translation, catholic-bible, deuterocanonical-books

Is there a Hebrew translation for the Deuterocanonical books (including 1,2 Maccabees)?  Any available online?

Comment: You're looking for modern Hebrew, to be clear?

Comment: Sure, any Hebrew translation.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_Hebrew#Apocrypha):

> Two major annotated Hebrew translations of the apocrypha were published in the 20th century. Both editions include commentaries by the editors, both are vowelized, and both of them incorporate parts of the original Hebrew for Ben Sira that were found in the Cairo Geniza and the Dead Sea Scrolls.
>
> - Avraham Kahana, ed. and trans., Ha-Sefarim ha-Hitsonim. Tel-Aviv: Hotsaat Meqorot, 1937 (2 vols.), most recently reissued in 2006.
> - Eliyah Shemuel Hartom (aka. Elia Samuele Artom), ed. and trans., Ha-Sefarim ha-Hitsonim. Tel-Aviv: Yavneh, 1965-69.

The Kahana translations are scanned [here](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Abraham%20Kahana%22).

Comment: Thanks @Alex, any translations available as text online?

Comment: @Mike Not that I've found for the apocrypha, unfortunately